# How did the Precursors know to invade earth? (Pacific Rim)

Tags: pacific-rim

The Pacific Rim wiki explains that the Precursors became interested in Earth during the Triassic period, or some pre-history time, but it wasn't suitable for them. Millions of years later, the pollution of humans renders Earth sustainable for the Precursors and cue invasion. But how did the Precursors know the time was right? There is no indication that they could watch the Earth, and the only hint we have that they glean any new information about Earth is the development of different Kaiju to fight the Jaegers, and the drift with the Kaiju brain. So if those are their only eyes into our world, as hinted, what told them that Earth was now ripe for colonization?

Answer (score 24):

Presumably small kaiju were sent from time to time to test. The Pacific ocean is huge, and if those arrivals occurred in early history, there would be no record of it. If any accounts did survive, they'd simply be today's myths of dragons or sea monsters. There exist enough weird legends from both East Asia and the sea-faring explorations of Europeans for this to be plausible.

Answer (score -1):

If in Pacific Rim's universe, the dinosaurs were indeed creations of the Precursors as the scientists states, then it's possible that the Precursors are still capable of watching Earth through the dinosaurs' fossils and skeletons who are preserved in museums and therefore can very much look on the outside world and its atmosphere. Of course it would be odd that paleontologists and other people who analyzed those skeletons for years never noticed some kind of "communication device" inside those bones but it's alien technology so it could work and look different enough than what we expect. After all, even a dead Kaiju's brain still had some form of telepathic connection to his creators, so maybe even dinosaurs skeletons could have some form of connection to them.

Comment: Answers are meant to provide some kind of evidence from within the story.  They are not supposed to be wild speculations.

Comment: If you have a better answer write one yourself. Besides, I don't see anyone being capable of writing a better kind of answers unless it works on the movie.